# Complementary sequence using gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I'm trying to make the complementary sequence of a dna chain stored in a vector.
It's supposed to change the "A" for the "T" and the "C" for the "G" and vice versa, the thing is, I need this to happen to the first vector and print the complementary sequence correctly. This is what I tried but got stucked:

```
pilot_sequence <- c("C","G","A","T","C","C","T","A","T")

complement_sequence_display <- function(pilot_sequence){
  complement_chain_Incom <- gsub("A", "T", pilot_sequence)
  complement_chain <- paste(complement_chain_Incom, collapse = "")
  cat("Complement sequence: ", complement_chain, "\n")
} 
complement_chain_Incom <- gsub("A","T", pilot_sequence)
complement_chain <- paste(complement_chain_Incom, collapse= "")
complement_sequence_display(pilot_sequence)
```

I got as answer: CGTTCCTTT,just the second and penultimate T are correct, how do I solve to the rest of letters ?

the pilot_sequence vector is character type and the functions displays no execution errors.

Answer (score 5):

This is a ideal use case for `chartr` function:

```
chartr("ATGC","TACG",pilot_sequence)
```

output:

```
[1] "G" "C" "T" "A" "G" "G" "A" "T" "A"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `purrr::map`:

```
pilot_sequence |> purrr::map_chr(~case_when(
  .x == "T" ~ "A",
  .x == "G" ~ "C",
  .x == "A" ~ "T",
  .x == "C" ~ "G"
))
#> [1] "G" "C" "T" "A" "G" "G" "A" "T" "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recode` from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

recode(pilot_sequence, "C" = "G", "G" = "C", "A" = "T", "T" = "A")
```

Or in base R, create a named vector and use `match` to match the values location in the named vector and then call `name` to get the names

```
pilot_sequence <- c("C","G","A","T","C","C","T","A","T")

values = c("G" = "C", "C" = "G", "A" = "T", "T" = "A")

names(values[match(pilot_sequence, values)])
```

```
"G" "C" "T" "A" "G" "G" "A" "T" "A"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It absolutly worked, I had to try with the second option since I have some problems installing packages, but you saved me.